# JavaScript multiple draggable DIV windows, zIndex on focus

Tags: javascript, z-index

I have multiple JavaScript draggable DIV windows. When clicking a DIV, I want the window to get the highest z-index value. I've made a solution by adding/removing classes to the element in focus, BUT, I would like the windows to keep their "layer" -order (as if the entire DIV window node was re-appended to the DOM when being clicked).

Let's say there are five DIV's in the DOM. div1, div2, div3, div4 and div5. -div5 is closest to the front and div1 is in the back and so on.

When clicking div1, -div1 will get focus and put to front, setting div5 back one step. Then clicking div3, -div3 gets closest to front and div1 and div5 are put back one step like this: div2, div4, div5, div1, div3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to do this without re-appending the element, my solution when I wrote something similar a while back was to keep track of the maximum z-index. Every time a window is brought forward, the maximum z-index is incremented and the element's z-index is set to the new value. Of course, if someone messes with the windows enough, they might end up having very large z-index values, so this isn't always the best solution.

```
var maximumZIndex = 1;
var bringForward = function (element) {
    maximumZIndex += 1;
    element.style.zIndex = maximumZIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to loop through all your divs and don't want to mess up with z-index you can just append again that div to the parent element (the body?) before dragging.

```
function stepUpNode(elementDragged){
    var parentNode = elementDragged.parentNode;
    parentNode.appendChild(elementDragged);
}
```

Comment: I've tried this but, this seems to remove the click-events inside the div when using IE. This also resets the div to its default state (changes done in the div such as scrolling or what ever is reset) each time it's appended.

Answer (score 0):

The first and most likely easiest approach: simply increase the maximum z-index every time a div gets selected. Since the z-index value can become pretty large (2147483647 if I remember correctly) you most likely will never run out of levels...

The following snippets use some jQuery:

```
var frontmostWindow = null;
var topZIndex = 10;    

$('div').click(function() {
     if (this != frontmostWindow) {
         frontmostWindow = this;
         topZIndex++;
         $(this).css('zLevel', topZIndex);

         // anything else needed to acticate your div
         // ...
     }
});
```

If you have restrictions on the z-indices you can use, you will need to re-assign levels every time a different div gets selected, e.g. like this:

```
// store z-index-ordered divs in an array 
var divs = $('div').toArray().sort(function(a, b) {
     return parseInt($(a).css('zIndex'), 10) - parseInt($(b).css('zIndex'), 10);
});

// store available z-indices
var zIndices = [];
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; ++i) {
    zIndices.push($(divs[i]).css('zIndex'));
}

// Event listener for clicks
$('div').click(function() {
    alert("heyya " + this.id);
    var element = this;

    var index = divs.indexOf(element);
    // check if clicked element is not already the frontmost
    if (index < divs.length - 1) {
        // remove div from array and insert again at end
        divs.splice(index, 1);
        divs.push(this);

        // re-assign stored z-indices for new div order
        for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; ++i) {
            $(divs[i]).css('zIndex', zIndices[i]);
        }

        // anything else needed to acticate your div
        // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: This works good. I've tried the first example, but without the jQuery.